# Footnotes on the wrong page with paracol and manyfoot

Tags: bigfoot, paracol, manyfoot

I am trying to set two texts, with corresponding 4 levels of footnotes, realized via manyfoot, on parallel facing pages, realized via manyfoot. See the following example, to which I added the normal footnotes, which probably are not handled by manyfoot, as they show the behavior I would expect, while those taken care of by manyfoot all appear on the same page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paracol}
\footnotelayout{c}

\usepackage[ruled,para*]{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{C}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{D}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}[1]*{2}
\lipsum[1]
\footnote{TextA}
\footnoteA{TextA}
\footnoteB{TextA}
\footnoteC{TextA}
\footnoteD{TextA}
\switchcolumn
\lipsum[2]
\footnote{TextB}
\footnoteA{TextB}
\footnoteB{TextB}
\footnoteC{TextB}
\footnoteD{TextB}
\switchcolumn
\lipsum[1]
\footnote{TextA}
\footnoteA{TextA}
\footnoteB{TextA}
\footnoteC{TextA}
\footnoteD{TextA}
\switchcolumn
\lipsum[2]
\footnote{TextB}
\footnoteA{TextB}
\footnoteB{TextB}
\footnoteC{TextB}
\footnoteD{TextB}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image: Footnotes page 1][image: Footnotes page 2]

Edit: Changing `\usepackage{manyfoot}` to `\usepackage{bigfoot}` for this example compiles without error but produces 0 pages of output. Weird.